# Getting pid of script run inside of shell - $! not giving anything

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that is runs a program using nohup that contains parameters, thus I wrap the command into a shell command. 
I am trying to get the pid of the program but am running into difficulties.
This is what I am trying to run:

```
nohup bash -c '../command --dir /mnt/raid/test/test.txt  "https://www.google.com/" > temp.txt 2>&1 &'; APP_PID=$! | {
            #APP_PID=$!
            echo "the pid is ${APP_PID}"
}
```

The result of this script shows an empty pid as below:

```
the pid is
```

I have tried numerous variations and have searched Stack Overflow but could not find anything related.

Question is what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background process is being created as a grand child of your shell (by `bash -c`) and you won't be able to get the PID of the grand child from the outer shell.  You could do this instead:

```
nohup bash -c '../command --dir /mnt/raid/test/test.txt  "https://www.google.com/" > temp.txt 2>&1'& APP_PID=$! && {
            echo "the pid is ${APP_PID}"
}
```

Here, `nohup` runs in background and you get its PID.

Comment: Thanks for that! It explains to me the confusion I had for the most part. Only issue now is that it spawns 2 pid's and this only captures one of them. Here is the result of  `ps aux`:

Comment: Sorry for the second comment. Forgot that Enter = submit comment. Here is what I was writing: Only issue now is that it spawns 2 pid's and this only captures one of them. Here is the result of  `ps aux` `root     32462  0.0  0.0  11140  1204 pts/3    S    15:14   0:00 ../command --dir /mnt/raid/test/test.txt  "https://www.google.com/" > temp.txt 2>&1
root     32464 39.2  0.1  81352 33868 pts/3    S    15:14   0:01 command --dir /mnt/raid/test/test.txt  "https://www.google.com/"` and the pid returned is 32462. How would I get the other pid?

Comment: What is there in ../command?  Is it a script?  Looks like it is forking a new process.

Comment: It is a python script if that helps

Comment: I only needed to kill the process and all child processes so the following command worked for what I needed: `pkill -TERM -P $APP_PID`. Thanks again! I am accepting your answer as it answers the question.